# Passing "this" as a context to a module?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm not a beginner but Javascript still often confuses me. Can someone tell me if what I am doing below is "ok"?

In Electron, the template code to set up menus can be very long. I have a number of menus in a multi-window app and I wanted to move the menu template code from `main.js` into a module.

So I created a new file:

```
const MenuTemplates = require("./app/js/menu-templates.js");
```

and call it like this:

```
var mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(MenuTemplates.getMainMenuFullVersion());`
```

Here is a truncated version of the menu template:

```
exports.getTimelineMenuFullVersion = function () {
    return [
        {
            label: global.appName,
            submenu: [
                { label: 'About ' + global.appName, 
                  click: () => { showAboutWindow() } },
```

Calling the functions (e.g. `showAboutWindow()` throws an error – and that surprised me. I guess I thought that since `MenuTemplates` is loaded by `main.js`, it would have access to its methods.

To address this I tried passing in `this` as context:

```
var mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(MenuTemplates.getMainMenuFullVersion(this));` 

exports.getTimelineMenuFullVersion = function (context) {
    return [
        {
            label: global.appName,
            submenu: [
                { label: 'About ' + global.appName, 
                  click: () => { context.showAboutWindow() } },
```

That didn't work – so now I am confused.

Comment: i try to understand in what context is `showAboutWindow`? quick check on electron doc has only showAboutPanel?

Comment: @Estradiaz – it's a custom function in `main.js` – not an `Electron` function.

Comment: most likely your main.js scope gets isolated - e.g. webpack - passing a context to fullfill an interface is common in my understanding - bundle your context into an object can be the next step

Answer (score 0):

for many years in ES5 i've used `jQuery.proxy()` https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/

however, with ES6 the scoping problem should solved for you, the fat arrow (=>) should be re-scoping the function for you. Unless i'm missing something.

Personally I would prefer the proxy pattern over passing the context around. But even better than that is to use the newer ES6 way of dealing with this

It's kind of impossible to answer exactly without seeing `MenuTemplates`. If `MenuTemplates` loads all its methods into the global namespace (`window`), then yes, in theory you'd have access to them anywhere.

But I don't think module loaded with require typically do that, they typically only load the variable in that file that is default (Look for `export default MenuTemplates` inside of app/js/menu-templates.js